# Get IP Address, Subnet, Default Gateway, DNS1 and DNS2 with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to click a button that updates multiple text labels or multiple text boxes with the network stack information. Here is the logic I'm after.

```
Button2 event 
Label1.text = Computer Name 
Label2.text = IP Address
Label3.text = Subnet Mask 
Label4.text = Default Gateway
Label5.text = DNS1
Label6.text = DNS2
```

I have some working code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim strHostName As String

    Dim strIPAddress As String


    strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()

    strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()



    TextBox2.Text = strIPAddress
    Lable_IPAddress.Text = strIPAddress


End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to get the default gateway or DNS's. The Subnet Mask isn't that important for what I'm trying to do but gateway and DNS entries are important.

I just want to click one button and have it show me a nicely formatted network stack. It doesn't seem like this should be that hard but I'm not that familiar with vb.net yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `NetworkInterface` class. It contains all informations what you want. You can get detailed information here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=vs.110).aspx

Simple usage:

```
'Computer Name
Label1.Text = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
For Each ip In System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Label1.Text).AddressList
    If ip.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
        'IPv4 Adress
        Label2.Text = ip.ToString()

        For Each adapter As Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface In Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            For Each unicastIPAddressInformation As Net.NetworkInformation.UnicastIPAddressInformation In adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
                If unicastIPAddressInformation.Address.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                    If ip.Equals(unicastIPAddressInformation.Address) Then
                        'Subnet Mask
                        Label3.Text = unicastIPAddressInformation.IPv4Mask.ToString()

                        Dim adapterProperties As Net.NetworkInformation.IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
                        For Each gateway As Net.NetworkInformation.GatewayIPAddressInformation In adapterProperties.GatewayAddresses
                            'Default Gateway
                            Label4.Text = gateway.Address.ToString()
                        Next

                        'DNS1
                        If adapterProperties.DnsAddresses.Count > 0 Then
                            Label5.Text = adapterProperties.DnsAddresses(0).ToString()
                        End If

                        'DNS2
                        If adapterProperties.DnsAddresses.Count > 1 Then
                            Label6.Text = adapterProperties.DnsAddresses(1).ToString()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I have been trying all kinds of different things and all of the tutorials and other things I've found weren't exactly what I was looking for or were using things like combo boxes and stuff that didn't translate over to how I wanted to use this information. I just wanted to click a button and have it display the network stack. Your code worked flawlessly for this purpose.Thanks.